# Proving language as regular

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

Suppose that A and B are languages such that A o B is regular. Suppose that B is regular. Prove or disprove that A is regular.

I am having a tough time with questions relating to proving a language as regular. Please help.

Comment: What does the circle mean?

Comment: the circle is supposed to be the concatenation sign

Comment: @user130417: Two questions. (1) By $A\circ B$ do you mean $\{ab:a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}$, the language that I’d denote simply by $AB$? (2) Are you familiar with non-deterministic finite state automata?

Comment: yes to both, i am currently learning about NFAs now

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a strong hint:

Think what happens when a language $L$ is concatenated with $\Sigma^*$.